# Call an API every X amount of time and save it in the Database

Tags: database, api, rest

Is there any tool online that has the ability to call an API every X (seconds/minutes/hours) amount of time and save or update the database accordingly?

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions provided.

Comment: Any programming language can do things on repeat, sleep for a set amount of time and write to a database. Pick one and break the problem down step by step.

Comment: I am looking for something like a tool and not a specific language basically some automation tool that i will code it to call an api and save response to a database and do that every 1 hour for example.

Comment: Then this question shoudl be closed. Doesn't sound like a programming problem, and asking for tool suggestions explicitly off-topic for stack-overflow